# For Firebase 3.0, what is the replacement for com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For **Firebase 3.0**, what is the replacement class for  `com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo`

This class is used in GeoFire, but I cannot find where the replacement for Repo is documented in any release notes.

Comment: Cross-post: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/26

Comment: And cross-posted again here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/firebase-talk/WKZmJmp0Il8

Answer (score 1):

`Repo` was an internal class that was not part of the official API and was therefore removed in the 3.0 release. GeoFire used the `Repo` class to schedule events on the right thread. What the right thread is depends on the context. On Android this usually is the main thread.

If you look at the [PR to update GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/pull/24), the absence of `Repo` is solved by dispatching events to the main thread on Android and to a new thread for vanilla Java.